# Javascript string with arguments to single quotes

Tags: javascript, string

Call function below relies in double and single quotes how can one convert this to single quotes only and get the same result?

```
const task.func = 'A'
const task.arg = 'B'
const callFunction = "doTask."+task.func+"('"+task.arg+"')"

console.log(callFunction); // doTask.A('B')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the single quotes:

```js
const task = {
  func: 'A',
  arg: 'B'
};
const callFunction = 'doTask.' + task.func + '(\'' + task.arg + '\')';

console.log(callFunction); // doTask.A('B')
```

Or, if you consider a backtick to be a single quote, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const task = {
  func: 'A',
  arg: 'B'
};
const callFunction = `doTask.${task.func}('${task.arg}')`;

console.log(callFunction); // doTask.A('B')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const callFunction = 'doTask.' + task.func + '(\'' + task.arg + '\')'
```

You need to escape the single quotes using a `\`

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling function `func` rather you are just creating a string which looks like function in below line ,

```
const callFunction = "doTask."+task.func+"('"+task.arg+"')";
```

Also you need not to use quotes, just provide variable name as argument.

Try like this.

```js
task = {};
task.func = function (arg){
  return 'func called with arg : '+arg;
};
task.arg = 'B';
const callFunction = 'doTask.'+task.func(task.arg);
console.log(callFunction);
```